# Peut-on ou doit-on dire "Internet" ou "l'internet"?

Tags: articles, noms-propres, noms

Il me semble qu'en général, on parle ***d'Internet***, mais il est encore fréquent d'entendre parler ***de l'internet***, quelle est la bonne forme ?

Même la page [wikipédia sur Internet](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:BmHFQHklO0gJ:fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet+site+fr.wikipedia.org+Internet+%22l'internet%22+%22l'Internet%22&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk) mélange toutes les écritures

Le [ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Internet,l%20%27%20internet,internet,l%27Internet&year_start=1990&year_end=2008&corpus=7&smoothing=3) semble confirmer mon impression, mais quelle est la règle à appliquer ?
[image]

Question connexe, faut-il mettre une majuscule à Internet ou le traiter en minuscule ?

Comment: Mais la courbe en bleu est exagérée puisqu'elle contient aussi toutes les autres formes...

Comment: @rds : hmmm, la comparaison doit se faire entre "Internet" et "internet" d'une part, et "l'Internet" et "l'internet" d'autre part . De plus, la comparaison NGram est sensible à la casse, donc "internet" ne rentre pas dans les stats d'"Internet".

Comment: Je suis d'accord pour la casse. Je faisais référence à l'usage de la particule: "Internet" inclut de fait "l' Internet". De plus, certains usages biaisent le résultat, par exemple _IP signifie Internet Protocol_ (dans ce cas, il n'y a pas l'article mais on parle d'autre chose)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

La Banque de dépannage linguistique de l'Office québécois de la langue française propose l'utilisation de la majuscule en raison du caractère propre de cette technologie. Une partie de l'[article](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=2&t1=&id=1637) :

> *Internet* est généralement considéré comme un nom propre; c'est la dénomination d'une réalité unique. Il ne s'agit pas d'une marque de commerce ni d'un organisme. On écrit donc *Internet* avec une majuscule initiale, tout comme son abréviation *Net*. C’est la majuscule qui sert à montrer qu'ils sont uniques. On observe aussi toutefois, dans l’usage actuel, l’emploi de la minuscule; on peut penser que l’on considère alors *Internet* comme un média parmi d’autres, au même titre que la télévision, la radio, la presse écrite; le nom internet, avec minuscule, serait ainsi traité comme un nom commun.
>
> On ne met généralement pas d'article devant les noms propres, car ils n'ont pas à être déterminés. Cependant, dans l'usage, l'article est fort répandu devant *Internet*; c’est peut-être parce qu’on le considère comme un nom commun (on écrit alors plutôt *internet*), ou parce qu’on considère qu’il s’agit de la forme abrégée de *réseau Internet*, où l'article se justifie. C’est peut-être aussi sous l'influence de l'anglais qu’on emploie l’article. Cependant, même si l'article *l'* est admis devant *Internet*, il reste préférable de ne pas mettre d'article devant ce nom. Notons que l'abréviation *Net*, elle, doit être précédée de l'article *le*.

L'OQLF contient également un article intéressant sur le choix de préposition à adopter avec Internet, intitulé *[Dans Internet ou sur Internet](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=2&t1=&id=1638)*.

Le Bureau de la traduction du gouvernement du Canada adopte une position semblable dans les *[Clefs du français pratique](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/clefsfp/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_catlog_i&page=9ap0iYj03kkA.html)* :

> On écrit de préférence **Internet** avec la majuscule, puisqu’il s’agit d’un nom propre. Toutefois, la graphie avec la minuscule est de plus en plus répandue, notamment lorsque le mot est précédé de l’article : *La télévision câblée, le téléphone mobile et l’internet pénètrent de plus en plus de foyers* (Le Nouvel Observateur).
>
> **Internet** peut être précédé ou non d’un article : *Non, c’est la faute à Internet, la démocratie en forme de bordel* (Le Devoir). *Dans vingt ans, que sera devenu Internet?* (Le Monde). *Avec l’arrivée de l’Internet, il se produit une rupture dans la relation entre la capacité de production et ce que l’on investit* (Le Point). *L’Internet est une chose merveilleuse, et il est excellent qu’il demeure hors de la mainmise des États* (Le Point). L’article est également facultatif lorsque le mot **Internet** est précédé d’une préposition : **sur Internet, sur l’Internet, dans Internet, dans l’Internet**.

Comment: j'irai plus loin en précisant qu'Internet est un espace et qu'en ce sens il peut avoir une représentation (imaginaire) géographique (bien que réparti), au même titre qu'une ville ou un pays, il porte un nom propre.

Answer (score 10):

Je suis assez vieux pour avoir appris la différence entre *un internet* qui est une interconnexion de réseaux et *Internet* (avec la majuscule) qui est le nom d'un internet particulier. *Intranet* a remplacé le nom commun *internet*, même s'il y a des nuances.

Pour *Internet*, certains utilisent *l'Internet*, mais il me semble que c'est d'autant plus rare que la personne est familière avec Internet.  Cet usage est rarissime dans mon milieu d'informaticiens et je ne le rencontre guère que dans les médias.

Comment: Pareil, je dirais juste Internet. Essayons de ne pas trop penser au classique « Au secours, mon internet est cassé !!! ».

Comment: Je suis d'accord, dans le monde informatique, on utilise quasi exclusivement Internet, mais ce n'est pas le monde qui fait le plus référence en matière d'orthographe ;)

Comment: Je n'ai jamais entendu *un internet* dans le sens que tu donnes, toujours *un intranet*.

Comment: @Gilles Il faut croire que tu n'es pas vieux assez.

Comment: @Gilles, si ton âge sur ton profil est correct, tu avais 12 ou 13 ans la dernière fois que je l'ai entendu.

Comment: @Unfrancophone Je serai plus subtile: un internet est une interconnexion de réseaux. Point. Locaux ou non.

Answer (score 8):

L'[exemple](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/internet) de l'Académie semble pointer vers *l'internet* :

> Un ordinateur connecté à l'internet.

La page [wikipédia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet) sur le sujet précise d'ailleurs que :

> Une [publication au Journal officiel de la République française](http://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/jopdf/common/jo_pdf.jsp?numJO=0&dateJO=19990316&numTexte=&pageDebut=03907&pageFin=) indique qu'il faut utiliser le mot « internet » comme un nom commun, c'est-à-dire sans majuscule.

Par contre, l'usage du nom propre *Internet* qui prédomine en anglais est poussé par pas mal d'internautes, et en particulier par le [Québec](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/1342), ce qui explique le peu de succès de l'Académié à imposer la minuscule. Nous nous trouvons de nouveau face à un cas d'opposition entre prescriptivisme (nom commun) et descriptivisme (nom propre). Pour ma part, je préfère rester sur le côté, un paquet de *[croustilles](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/croustilles)* à la main.

En passant, le problème s'est sans doute aussi posé dans d'autres langues ; ainsi en néerlandais par exemple, la dénomination *[het internet](http://woordenlijst.org/zoek/?sourceid=Mozilla-search&q=internet)* est officielle depuis 2005.

Comment: Je ne fais pas trop confiance aux académiciens pour être au courant des nouvelles technologies. Pour moi, c'est Internet, car à l'heure actuelle, il n'y a qu'un réseau portant ce nom. De même, je parle du Net, voire du Web. Et j'évite de parler d'email, trop proche de l'émail, je préfère e-mail. Ou à la rigueur de courriel !

Comment: @PhiLho Tu parles donc de Soleil, et non pas du soleil ?

Answer (score 7):

D'après Jean-Pierre Lacroux (voir le site consacré à son ouvrage [Orthotypographie](http://www.orthotypographie.fr/volume-II/madame-mythologie.html)

> « l’emploi d’Internet sans article traduit une adhésion, consciente ou inconsciente, à l’idéologie marchande ».

Il soutient l'usage de « l'Internet » (majuscule *et* article) arguant qu'elle

> « semble mieux exprimer la nature initiale de ce réseau et une tentative de résistance (certes un peu dérisoire) ».

La discussion présentée sur le site décortique plusieurs arguments
courants en faveur des différentes formes.

Il me semble qu'ici, comme dans bien d'autre cas, les deux formes sont défendables et permettent d'introduire une nuance qui peut être intéressante.

*Ajout visant à clarifier un point soulevé par les commentaires*

Le statut de nom propre (et donc la majuscule) n'est pas remit en question ici.
C'est essentiellement la question de la présence ou non de l'article qui est soulevée.
C'est pourquoi il me semble plus logique d'écrire « Internet [portant la connotation d'une marque] pollue l'Internet [le réseau aux si nobles aspirations] ».

Comment: discussion très intéressante :)

Comment: Cela semble être l'explication la plus efficace, celle qui reflète le plus les faiblesses linguistiques du mercantilisme. On pourrait même dire : l'internet pollue Internet.

Comment: N'est-ce pas plutôt : Internet pollue l'Internet ?

Comment: Non. Si "(l')Internet" un nom propre, c'est parce qu'il n'y en a qu'un; non pas des reseaux nationaux, ou commerciaux, mais un reseau global, non-proprietaire et unique. C'etait la vision de ses createurs et des premiers soutiens de l'Internet puis du Web; c'est par son action pour un reseau non-mercantile que Tim Berners-Lee a ete annobli, et non pas pour un succes commercial, dont il s'est prive en faveur du service public. L'Internet est un reseau public mondial, cree par des gens au service du public, dans une vision de la technologie au service de l'humanite.

Comment: @Alfred M. : "boisvert" à fait une réponse qui établi bien la fracture entre la pureté d'intention de l'Internet des origines, et l'internet 'bankable'. Tonton Fredo (Nietzsche) parle de "renversement des valeurs". Ou encore le Verbe se transforme en bla-bla, casse (toutes acceptions) comprise.

Answer (score 2):

Je pense que tout le monde s'accorde sur l'usage de la majuscule.

En revanche, ma réponse diffère des autres parce que je fais partie de ceux qui placent régulièrement l'article pour parler de *l'Internet*, en traduction directe de l'usage anglais *the Internet*. Par exemple la page [Wikipedia Internet (en)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet).

> The Internet is a global system of interconnected computer networks

C'est l'usage le plus courant en anglais, il me semble. En tout état de cause, c'est l'usage historique.

Initialement, le réseau militaire s'appelait Arpanet et le terme générique *internet* est une contraction de *an internetwork*, c'est-à-dire un réseau de réseaux. Dans le [TCP Digets Vol. 1 #10](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/fa.tcp-ip/xpOn9vG0FRA/Ei35HJY5-nwJ) on lit ainsi

> Arpanet is expected to become **an internet**  -- a network of networks -- ... said an informed source, who revealed the cutover date.

Avec le temps ARPA/Arpanet disparaît. Bien plus tard, alors que l'Internet est utilisé par le grand-public, on lit (La Netiquette, alias [RFC 1855](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1855.txt) publiée en 1995)

> In the past, the population of people using **the Internet** had "grown
>     up" with the Internet, were technically minded, and understood the
>     nature of the transport and the protocols.

Personnellement, j'emploie les deux selon l'humeur. Je crois que la présence de la particule diffère aussi. *L'internet est né dans les années 80* ; *J'ai cherché sur Internet, et je n'ai rien trouvé*. Je n'emploie jamais *dans (l')Internet*.

Answer (score 2):

Si *Internet* a pu être le nom propre qui désignait un réseau encore confidentiel, son adoption par le monde entier en a fait un mode universel de transmission du son et des images, comme la télévision, la radio, le téléphone, la vidéo. Il ne fait donc aucun doute qu'il a perdu sa majuscule et qu'il doit être précédé de l'article défini, comme l'ont bien vu l'Académie et les linguistes compétents. Il est d'ailleurs cocasse de voir que ceux qui s'obstinent dans l'erreur en refusant l'article sont les premiers à dire « le net » quand il s'agit du diminutif. Comme dans la déclaration péremptoire « il faut écrire Internet quand il s'agit du net ! ». Mais encore, savent-ils que le partitif *du* veut dire « de le » ?

Comment: Tout à fait d'accord avec cette réponse. Ce mot s'utilise d'ailleurs dans d'autres circonstances telles que l'internet des objets. S'agit-il d'une sous-partie d'Internet ou doit-on le considérer comme un nouveau réseau différent d'Internet, dans son fonctionnement et sa structure. Quand à l'intranet, c'est un réseau interne d'une organisation. C'est donc clairement dénombrable.

Comment: N'importe quoi internet est internet il est une abération grave de dire l'internet  ou pire encore les internet. Ce n'est pas parce que c'est une régle établie qu'il ne faut pas la combattre :)

Answer (score 1):

> L'internet

est une erreur. Certains se moquent d'ailleurs de cette utilisation en l'éxagérant, en parlant de "les internets".

Comme dit plus haut, on désignera une utilisation correcte sans article

> "Bienvenue sur Internet"

Les utilisations erronnées (avec articles) seront faites de personnes qui le plus souvent ne comprennent pas la nature de cette technologie, ou par moquerie de ces personnes.