# Is it “sur Internet” or “dans Internet”?

Tags: prépositions

This morning, I encountered the following sign:

[image: sur Internet vs dans Internet]

French is not my mother tongue, but my guts tell me that the phrase *sur Internet* is the correct one, but it is only because I have seen it many times before, I cannot actually find a formal explanation.

Can someone put some light on this by:

1. Confirming or denying that *dans Internet* is not a correct usage
2. Explaining why (with some grammar rules, if there is any)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would have instinctively answered **sur Internet** at once.

Then I checked on [wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet), it confirms. Ngram confirms too:

[image: ngram]

The [*Banque de dépannage linguistique*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=1638), however, discusses it, and they seem reserved on the matter, showing examples of both uses.

Comment: “Dans Internet” may be a québécisme, I join my voice to the French natives who find it odd. Looking at [occurrences of “dans Internet” on the web](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22dans+internet%22) (and eliminating “dans Internet Explorer”), they seem to be predominantly in `.ca` domains.

Comment: I wouldn't give much credits to the *Banque*'s "examples" as they are 100% made-up (as opposed to citations as you'd find in Grevisse or the OED) and thus useless from a lexicographical/scientific point of view.

Comment: @Circeus I don't give them *much* credit neither, but I'm quoting them as an example of another point of view. By the way, I mainly disagree with them. Just sort of adding some material to discuss.

Answer (score 10):

I'd use ***sur Internet***, as *dans Internet* sounds very odd to me (native).

On the other hand, “Internet” being first and foremost an *English* word, **there are no golden rules** for *French* prepositions to use with it.

In [this related question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1335/peut-on-ou-doit-on-dire-internet-ou) is asked whether “internet” should be capitalized, and if an article should be used or not with it (→ “an Internet”) — demonstrating more of this no-rule situation.

Answer (score 5):

Je soupçonne que ceux qui appliquent *dans* de manière systématique font appel à une espèce de fétichisme logicien. La chasse aux sorcières contre une théorique ambigüité (qui ne se produit presque jamais en pratique) est un thème récurrent à l'origine de ce genre de ne-dtites-pas-mais-dites, comme je l'ai noté [dans une réponse précédente](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/2236/926).

En l'occurrence, je crois que c'est une surgénéralisation (qui plus est contre l'usage: *surfer/naviguer sur Internet* est tellement plus fréquent que *une information sur Internet* que la prédominance de *sur* n'a rien de surprenant) de cette remarque dans l'entrée de la BDL à laquelle Romain fait référence qui est à l'origine de l'emploi favorisé de *dans* par certaines personnes (peut-être alimenté par d'autres guides d'usage, mais ni Ramat ni de Villers ne sont alors responsables):

> Toutefois, lorsqu’on utilise *sur*, il peut y avoir ambiguïté dans certains emplois. Dans le dernier exemple ["Maurice a trouvé cet article sur Internet."], le lecteur peut se demander si Maurice a trouvé un article en naviguant sur Internet ou s’il a plutôt trouvé un article à propos d’Internet.

Comment: Pardon, je voulais faire référence à la Banque de Dépannage Linguistique (BDL), mais comme je consulte le Grand Dictionnaire Terminologique (GDT) beaucoup plus souvent, d'où mon lapsus. Par le "fétichisme logicien" j'entends cette attitude (pas toujours pertinente d'ailleurs) qu'on rencontre souvent derrière les arguments puristes (et pas qu'en français d'ailleurs) selon laquelle les mots et les constructions ne doivent avoir qu'un seul et unique sens et qu'un des des règles est d'éliminer de manière absolue toute ambigüité.

Comment: Merci d'avoir clarifié.

Answer (score 3):

It is the same thing in both French and English :

- English : **on** the Internet.
- French : **sur** Internet.

Comment: -1, analogies between languages is not a way to confirm that something is correct or not.

Comment: +1, as the preposition following the noun in its travel from English to French makes a lot of sense for me.

Comment: Nikana is right, unlike "Un francophone". That's why I gave a +1 to Nikana's comment.

Answer (score 3):

J'ai toujours vu/lu 
"Aller sur Internet, le/un site, la/une plateforme". 
"Naviguer sur le site/ la plateforme".
"Être sur le site, la plateforme, Internet, un/le moteur de recherche...."

Sur Internet, on n'est pas dans un espace (physique ou virtuel) fermé. On n'est pas enfermé à l'intérieur de quoi que ce soit. On est en tout cas "sur" car on "navigue", on "marche" sans de limites précises, on bouge librement (c'est-à-dire on peut aller vers/sur d'autres sites/liens et même "entrer" dans d'autres espaces toujours sur un même site).
Quand on est sur Internet, on n’est pas DANS une toile. Sur Intenet, on se promène SUR la grande Toile du cyberespace comme sur une rue/avenue. Lorsqu'on utilise "sur" on a, on éprouve un sentiment/esprit d'ouverture, d'infini.

Mais je suis née cubaine, donc je suis née DANS l'espagnol :-). 
Je n'ai pas la réponse définitive.

Answer (score 1):

Both are good. It is a question of perception as it is often the case for relatively new constructs. Not everything id bound by rules. Rules are often set overtime when usage is fixed, a reality the BDL diligently takes into account.
"Sur" is more common, but not necessarily "more right". Not yet at least.

Answer (score 0):

Réponse : **Sur** l'Internet.

L'Internet est bien un domaine, mais ce n'est pas un domaine comme un parc. Un parc ou une ville peuvent contenir quelque chose dans les murs donc on peut dire "dans un parc" mais si on dit **dans L'Internet** la phrase perd son sens.

Comment: However, many valid uses of the preposition *dans* are metaphoric and don't really convey the meaning of *physically containing* but *being part of* or else. Examples : *Il est sorti de l'adolescence.*, *Il s'est engagé dans l'armée.*

Comment: ...et en suivant le même raisonnement (en réduisant la préposition à son sens spatial), on ne peut pas non plus utiliser *sur l'Internet*, car les pages ne se situent pas *physiquement au-dessus* de l'Internet. L'usage abstrait ou figuré qu'on accorde à la préposition *sur*, on ne peut pas le refuser à *dans* me semble-t-il. Non pour contester ta réponse (car je suis d'accord) mais plutôt les raisons invoquées.

Answer (score -3):

Mon avis est il faut dire **dans Internet**.

Tout comme on ne dit jamais j'ai lu un article **sur** le journal, un chapitre **sur** le livre, on ne peut pas dire que l'on consulte un article **sur** Internet.

Mon exemple de site web était effectivement contradictoire. Mon opinion reste tout de même que le terme le plus respectueux de la syntaxe et de la structure de phrase du français est d'utiliser **dans** Internet lorsque l'on se réfère à de l’information que l’on consulte.

Mon raisonnement est le suivant;

Lorsque je lis un article **sur** le journal, je lis un article dont le sujet est le journal.

Le journal est l'ensemble dans lequel se retrouvent les pages. Exactement comme Internet est l'ensemble des réseaux dans lesquels se retrouvent les sites web, blog et cie.

D'ailleurs, l'[OQLF](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=1638) fait cette même distinction.

> Toutefois, lorsqu’on utilise sur, il peut y avoir ambiguïté dans
>   certains emplois. Dans le dernier exemple, le lecteur peut se demander
>   si Maurice a trouvé un article en naviguant sur Internet ou s’il a
>   plutôt trouvé un article à propos d’Internet.

Aussi, contrairement à une page dans un livre ou encore un journal, Internet n’est pas un support en soit. Il s’agit d’un lien vous donnant accès à plusieurs réseaux.

Encore une fois, l'[OQLF](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8361867) en fait mention dans la définition du mot Internet.

*Par métonymie, Internet peut être considéré comme un support virtuel, mais non comme un support électronique. En effet, Internet n'est pas un support physique sur lequel sont stockées les données consultées, c'est un lien qui permet d'accéder à des ressources. Une ressource Internet peut par exemple être un système de recherche (Gopher, Web), une base de données accessible par FTP ou un service de courrier électronique.*

> Ce que l'on retrouve **sur Internet**, ce sont des 1 et des 0.*

Dogmatique, peut-être, mais la langue française est rempli de d'exemple où l'orthographe ou la syntaxe nous est imposé par pur dogmatisme.

Finalement, je suis d'avis qu'il est possible de dire « je lis un article sur un site web », par contre mon énoncé peut-être interprété de deux façons différentes.

Je ne suis toujours pas convaincu que l'on peut dire sur Internet pour faire référence à autre chose que les données (1 et 0) qui y transitent. Surtout qu'Internet, est d’abord et avant tout un nom propre.

L’administrateur réseau en moi me force à dire qu’Internet ne peut pas être utilisé pour désigner le médium **sur** lequel repose les pages web.

Internet désigne surtout, de par son nom propre, le projet par lequel différents réseaux se sont interconnectés.

À l’opposé, la toile ne me pose pas la même problématique.

Comment: Il y a comme un petit côté dogmatique infondé qui me chagrine un peu, pour un emploi aussi rare. Heureusement, c'est **dans** une réponse appréciable **sur** la Toile, pas couché **sur** le papier **dans** une bibliothèque. Je ne serais pas contre une analyse un peu plus fine de tous ces parallèles…

Comment: Voilà, j’ai étoffé ma réponse. En espérant être plus clair dans mon raisonnement.

Comment: Soit. C'est devenu justifié, donc je retire *dogmatique*. Par contre, je ne suis toujours pas d'accord, et c'est le plus exemplaire là : « Je ne suis toujours pas convaincu que l'on peut dire sur Internet pour faire référence à [ce qu'on veut] ». Si ta position s'était tenue, tu aurais écrit ***puisse*** *se tenir*. Seulement, elle ne se tient pas, puisqu'on peut, puisqu'une écrasante majorité de locuteurs le font. Que ce soit parce qu'ils n'ont pas la moindre idée de ce qu'est le réseau en question est peut-être un autre problème, mais n'en est pas moins une réalité.

Comment: Le problème c'est que je n'ai pas dit _[ce qu'on veut]_. J'étais précis sur ce qui **peut** ce retrouver **sur** Internet. Aussi, le fait que "l’écrasante majorité" de locuteurs le fait ne veut certainement pas dire que c'est la bonne chose à faire. La population en générale utilise **sur**, j’en suis d’accord, mais lorsque le terme est utilisé dans un cadre plus "officiel" c’est **dans Internet** que je vois/entends le plus souvent.

Comment: Par *ce qu'on veut*, j'entend *ce que je, auteur, veux*, i.e. *des articles, et tout sauf des bits*, et avec lequel tu n'es pas d'accord. Je dis que ce dont tu dis que ça ne peut pas se trouver *sur* Internet **peut** être dessus. Pour le reste, j'ai l'impression que nos différends sont clairs.

Comment: Agree to disagree...